# Is cog ratio the only relevant factor

Tags: belt-drive, gates, pinion

I’m planning on changing my drive from chain to Gates belt drive.

My current drive is 30t front and rear giving 1:1

The available Gates sprockets for me are practically 32T front/rear.

Instinctively I think that the 1:1 from the new drive will be identical to what I have now. Am I missing some subtlety about different cog pitch or is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the only factor.

Some will add that larger cogs last longer (less pressure on the teeth), are more efficient, but can be heavier and require the appropriate clearance on the frame, but between 30T and 32 that would remain marginal (assuming a similar tech). Frame clearance can be an issue if you are at the limit as they are wider than chains.